# how do i call webservice from MVC3 Razor Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

In my project I need to call a web service from a controller. I have already done the following, and it works.

1. Add the web reference for the web service to the project.
2. Call the service as follows:

   ```
   Service Wservice=new Service();
   Wservice.loginCompleted+=new Wservice_login_Completed;
   WService.login_Async("username","Password");
   ```

   Note: Whenever i call this service it throws an error that is 
   "An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time.
   Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler 
   or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this
   exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked 
   <%@ Page Async="true" %>."

To overcome this issue I use

```
 [Httppost]
 public ActionResult login(logmodel model)
 {
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    { 
    Wservice.loginCompleted+=new Wservice_login_Completed;
    WService.login_Async("username","Password");
    });

    if(finalresult==true)
    {
      *** return View();
    }
  }

  void Wservice_login_completed()
  {
      Here i got the output.
  }
```

But the calling of Wservice_login_completed() function was after the View*** was returned,, so I'm not getting the result. How do I achieve "calling webservice from Controller".. Any ideas?

Comment: Are u using `AsynController` ?

Comment: My hunch here is that this has something to do with Page render cycle, can you post HTTP request from browser web developer tools, also I doubt if you are actually in asynchronous mode.

Comment: Why are you using a web reference instead of a service reference? That's part of the legacy "ASMX" technology and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Can you kindly explain what exactly you want to suggest when you said **Why are you using a web reference instead of a service reference?**

Comment: @PankajGarg: I suggest using a service reference

Comment: No i'm not using AsynController @PankajGarg

Comment: @JohnSaunders let me try it

Comment: @JohnSaunders how i can call a service Reference?

Comment: See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i called the webservice from MVC Controller Successfully.

Note: **Add ServiceReference instead of WebReference and avoid

         "Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>);" Process.**

```
  [Httppost]
 public ActionResult login(logmodel model)
 {
    Wservice.ServiceSoapClient _host = new Wservice.ServiceSoapClient("ServiceSoap");

    var result_out = _host.login(uname, pwd, "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4");
 }
```

Here "ServiceSoap" is an endpoint for our service.. you may got the endpoint to be presented in app.confiq or web.config files.
Happy Coding...!

Answer (score 0):

1. get the following NuGet:

   ```
   microsoft http client   
   (id = Microsoft.Net.Http)
   ```
2. Create a Web API Controller (webapi_Controller_Name)
   Your Post function should be similar to the following function
   Put this function in your Web Api Controller

   ```
   [HttpPost]  
   public void PostForm(objUser ws_Obj)  
   {   
       // put you code here
   }
   ```
3. Call your Web Service from you regular Controller as follows.
   This is an Async call and will Web Service will return immediately.

   ```
   //call the web service, Asynch        
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();    
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("52323/");    
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   client.PostAsJsonAsync("//52323/api/webapi_Controller_Name/PostForm", objContact);
   ```

Comment: I apologize for the formatting, but the editor was very picky, I numbered the steps for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a service reference by right clicking on the project name in the solution explorer, then hover over the "Add" option and click on "Service Reference..."

Second, paste your web service address in the "Address" field of the "Add Service Reference" page, be sure to add "?wsdl" to the end of your web service address or it won't work, and then press "Go". You will see the web service appear in the "Services" area. Click on the service to see the available services which will appear in the "Operations" section. Rename the service if you want, then press OK to create the service.

Finally, put the following code in your MVC Controller. Place the code in a Get or Post controller, it doesn't matter.

```
    // Declare the Request object.
    ServiceReference1.GetSurveyRequest myGSRq = new ServiceReference1.GetSurveyRequest();

    // You can set the webservice parameters here like...
    myGSRq.Address = getUserData[0].address;
    myGSRq.City = getUserData[0].city;
    myGSRq.State = getUserData[0].state;

    // Now declare the Response object.
    ServiceReference1.GetSurveyResponse myGSR = new ServiceReference1.GetSurveyResponse();

    //And then use the following to process the request and response.
    ServiceReference1.EMPortTypeClient emptc = new ServiceReference1.EMPortTypeClient();
    myGSR = emptc.GetSurvey(myGSRq);

    // In this example the response Object comes back with a URL used to redirect the user 
    //after the webservice has been processed.
    if (myGSR.Url != null)
        Response.Redirect(myGSR.Url.ToString());
    else
        Response.Write("Error");
    return null;
```

Pretty simple, hope this helps!

If you are creating a new service and have the option of using a webservice or a Web API, I suggest using Web API.
[Build RESTful API's with ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api#Exercise3)